# Displaying image in a VB form Picture Box at runtime

Tags: vb.net, image

I am designing an app and I want to attach some pictures to my VB forms. I have used a picture box and the image is only visible before I debug. Once debugging starts, the image disappears.

How do I display the image when I run the debugger? This is the code I used for the picture box:

```
PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.tropical_island3
```

Comment: I think you need to include more code - not sure what you're doing here.  And is this VB.Net?

Comment: It is VB.NET, otherwise there'd be no `My.Resources`.

Comment: Do you mean, when you break into the debugger and step through the code the image disappears?  Or when running the form in DEBUG mode?

Comment: when i run the form in debug mode,is when the image disappears. I tried it on vb 2005 in class and it run fine. I dont know why it wont run on vb 2008 exprerss

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem on a VB.NET form. I found when loading the form as a modal window (`.ShowDialog`) the image in the picture box showed fine, but if loading the form as non-modal (`.Show`) the `PictureBox` showed with a white background.

To resolve showing the image in the non-modal form, I needed to call `.Refresh` for the form after the `.Show`

Hope that helps someone else!

Comment: sonyisda1 and Neolisk: Thank you so much for your answer.I was running in the same situation from yesterday finally your .Refresh approach helps me.One question I am using .gif image to show in the loading screen but .gif image animation is not working.Now picture box just showing image no movement.Do you have any idea about this situation.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possibility, based on the limited info:

If the image is shown in the picturebox before you run the form in debug mode, then it apparently has been assigned at design time to the PictureBox1.Image property. When you run the program and assign My.Resources.tropical_island3 to the Picture Box image, it clears the image because My.Resources on your home computer does not have tropical_island3 like the one at class, or maybe tropical_island3 is spelled incorrectly.